# Find the reason why "ls /tmp" doesn't work in a security exploit

Tags: permissions

I have managed to `execve("/bin/sh")` in an Apache process, as a security exercise.
The ls command works fine for example in the root and in `/bin`, but not in `/tmp`, where it outputs nothing even if the dir is world readable.
Furthermore, I created a a file foo in `/tmp`, changed owner to `www-data` yet I get  `cat: /tmp/foo: No such file or directory`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `PrivateTmp=true` ?

Comment: There are multiple mitigations to block this exploit, some in the operating system and some in apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Artem, apache or php-fpm may be running as a systemd service with `PrivateTmp=true` mentioned here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

That would result in the web server running in its own mount namespace with a different `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` to the rest of the system.

Assuming this is the problem you can use `nsenter` to execute your script in the namespace of another process.  Process ID 1 should be in the same namespace to the majority of your system.

```
nsenter -mt 1 /bin/sh
```